# i am getting faces exception "abc" cannot be refrenced from zoo

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, clientid, ajax-update

I have scenario where selecting a value in drop down my panel id=abc should display.But i am getting faces exception "abc" cannot be refrenced from zoo.
    Any suggestion for code improvemnt....
    Thanks in advance...

```
    <p:selectOneMenu id="zoo" value="#{cc.attrs.bean.test}" style="width:150px"  label="#{hello.description}" 
            converter="testConverter">
                 <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{cc.attrs.bean.onTest}" update="abc"/>
                 <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.bean.sooo}" var="soh" itemLabel="#{soh.ex1}" itemValue="#{soh}"/>
             </p:selectOneMenu>

             <p:accordionPanel style="width:580px;" id="xyz">
    <p:tab title="Test for tab"id="hfg">
    <p:outputPanel style="width:525px;display:block" id="abc" > 
<ui:repeat id="foo" value="#{cc.attrs.bean.animal}" var="yyy">
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{!yyy.aaa}"  id="ppp">
<h:outputText value="#{yyy.flower />
<p:selectOneMenu id="wooo" value="#{yyy.house}" label="#{yyy.car}" converter="yyyConverter">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />  
<f:selectItems value="#{yyy.example}" var="sss" itemLabel="#{sss.p1}:#{sss.dp2}" itemValue="#{sss}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
</h:panelGroup>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: I have edited my code.Now i am getting a problem where the page is not refreshing and loading all the data from db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to update an element (p:outputPanel) which is embedded in another element (p:tab) with an id and of which the p:tab is embedded too in an p:accordionPanel with an id. You have to specify all the parents ids in the update attribute like below:

```
  <p:selectOneMenu id="zoo" value="#{cc.attrs.bean.test}" style="width:150px"  label="#{hello.description}" 
    converter="testConverter">
         <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{cc.attrs.bean.onTest}" update="xyz:hfg:abc"/>
         <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.bean.sooo}" var="soh" itemLabel="#{soh.ex1}" itemValue="#{soh}"/>
  </p:selectOneMenu>

  <p:accordionPanel style="width:580px;" id="xyz">
  <p:tab title="Test for tab" id="hfg">
    `enter code here`
    <p:outputPanel style="width:525px;display:block" id="abc" >    
    </p:outputPanel>
  </p:tab>
```

You should also put a space between the title and the id of your p:tab with id=hfg.

Comment: Thanks for the ans.It is working great but the id which i am updating is not gettting refreshed while selecting the dropdown...

Comment: I see no value embedded in your component with id="abc". I think you have to enter your code there.

Comment: I have edited the code and i have also  debuged the controller class to confirmed that all the values are there.

Comment: @BalusC can you help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827254/deleting-a-wrong-value-in-jsf2-2